# One to one combine array values

Tags: php, arrays

I having trouble with combining array values.

```
<?php
$data =[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'X',
            'Y',
            'Z'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'A',
            'B'
        ],
    ]
];
```

That array can be min. 1 or unlimited item in Foo -never empty-, Also min. 1 or unlimited item in Bar. Bar's values can be greater than Foo values.

It's what I want to accomplished:

```
<?php
$data =[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'X'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'A'
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'Y'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'A'
        ],
    ]
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'Z'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'A'
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'X'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'B'
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'Y'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'B'
        ],
    ]
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'Foo' => [
            'Z'
        ],
        'Bar' => [
            'B'
        ],
    ]
];
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

the question is about combining, but your example is splitting.
try to tell what's your objectives, probably we can help better that way.